# Index is changing on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Ok, it's hard to explain, but I'll try.

I wrote an ng-repeat which goes over an JSON which I obtain from an HTTP request. The results are presented and one can see details of the result by clicking on the detail button.

In my JSON there are two elements with the same price. My entire presentation is ordered by price. If I click on the details of the first element with price x, the details of the second element with price x are shown and furthermore the order of the results is changed. If I then close again the details the order goes back again.

I dont know how to set up such an complex JSfiddle. I hope you can help me in this matter.

```
showDetails($parent.$index)
```

Here is some code snippet:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in data|orderBy:order">
  <div ng-repeat="leg in legs.result">
   <span>{{leg.example}}</span><span>{{result.price}}</span>
   <div ng-click="showDetails($parent.$index)">

  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="leg in legs.result" ng-show="details[$parent.$index]">
    {{leg.details}} 
  </div>
</div>
```

here comes the show details function.

```
for(var i = 0;i<$scope.data.length;i++) {
        $scope.details[i] = false;
      }

$scope.order='price'
 $scope.showDetails=function(i){
        $scope.details[i]=!$scope.details[i];
}
```

And the JSON might look something like this:

```
[{
price:700,
legs:[{
example:"test",
details:"testDetail1"}]

},
price:800,
legs:[{
example:"test2",
details:"testDetail2"}]
},
{
price:800,
legs:[{
example:"test3",
details:"testDetail3"}]
}]
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code so we can see what you are trying to do...

Comment: Try posting an example of the json data with just a few records in it, and the ng-repeat html - that shouldn't be too much code and would probably help a lot.